# How to hide the time part using bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, eonasdan-datetimepicker

How to hide the time in my datetime picker?

I want to hide my timer bar in my calendar control.

When I select my date by default it shows the time in textbox, I want to hide that in my text input and in my calendar too.

Moreover I want to hide past dates.

Here I have created [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rC8uAg22M2qfnVmngFcZ?p=preview)

```
<div class='col-sm-6'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show only date use `format: 'L'`.
The previous dates can be disabled by using `minDate`.

```
$('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
    format: 'L',
    minDate: new Date()
});
```

See updated plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/9RIbRxwm5N0Ap8Chhdsm?p=preview).

Comment: Hi Taleeb, how to restrict previous date.

Comment: Hi Taleeb, Is there any way to change symbol of next, previous button

Comment: Hi taleeb , if i want month and year means what should change in format

Comment: @Vinoth you can use [icons](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#icons) option of the datetimepicker. Please do not add new requirements in the comments, edit your question or post a new one. Moreover, always look at the docs and other stack overflow posts and try to solve your issue by yourself before asking a question.